# Count the number of Triplet that have a middle in an ordered list (e.g. second-first=third-second) in O(n*constant)

Tags: python, algorithm, complexity-theory

I have an ordered list with positive integer (randomly selected from 0 up to 2 million), I need to find the number of possible triplet that match this condition:
difference between the second and the first equal the difference between the third and the second. In other words, here an ordered triplet: (x,y,z), I need: y-x=z-y. One necessary condition is that the problem resolve itself in **O(n) or O(n*logn)**.

The number of possible difference is unknown as well as if triplets exist.

For instance here it is an example: list is [1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 10, 11]
there is 4 distinct differences but 1 give 2 different triplet so 5 triplet in total that have a middle.

**Triplet, Difference**

[1,4,7]   3

[4,7,10]  3

[3,7,11]  4

[7,9,11]  2

[9,10,11] 1

So I though of a simple algorithm (**O(n^2)**) but it takes way too much time:
(maxi is almost like the maximum of the list)

```
    c=set(lst)
    count=0
    for i in range(len(lst)):
      flag=1
      k=i+1
      while k<len(lst) and flag:
        e=lst[k]
        diff = e - lst[i]
        if diff * 2 > maxi:
            flag = 0
        if (e + diff) in c:
            count += 1
        k+=1
    print(count)
```

The repl of the full algorithm responding to this problem: https://prologin.org/train/2018/qualification/crepes_parfaites https://repl.it/@elisafirenzoe/SecondSuspiciousFalcon

I thought of other solutions such as using an AVL or a hashmap but due to the unknown differences I can't figure out all the triplets, I looked at the subset sum problem but it doesn't seems to respond to my request.

Interesting enough, but not sure how I could applied it as I don't know which elements will be a middle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM

Comment: I think O(n^2) is the best you can do, because if all of the integers in the list are equally spaced the number of results scales as ~ n^2, which gives a lower bound to the algorithm.

Comment: I don't think that's possible in `O(n)`

Comment: That's what i first though but the problem seems to be solved in less than O(n^2) (so O(n*log(n) or O(n*constant)) as this example didnt go through the test case.

Comment: Are you sure you need to produce the triplets? Or only the count of them?

Comment: only the count, the triplets are here to explain the problem

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying that in your edit.

Comment: I assume `in` would iterate through the entire list (e.g. be O(n)) - but if you store your data in a hash table, you can do that check in O(1).

Comment: so i did make a few change to reduce the time the in operation take, namely i switch to set but it isnt fast enough to still pass the tests (it helped reduce time for one case tho).

Comment: You probably can speed things up more by implementing the set with an indicator array (_i.e._ a[n] can be true/false, indicating whether value n occurs or not) -- since n is at most 2 millions, this is not prohibitive in terms of memory (and it simplifies that "in", the most frequently performed operation, , _e.g._ by not needing to compute hashcodes).